# How can I call LimitText without causing an exception with derived CComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, combobox

I have my own class called `CDynComboBox` which is derived from `CComboBox`. In the constructor I made this call to `LimitText`:

```
CDynComboBox::CDynComboBox()
: m_bHandleComboItemDeleted(false)
{
    LimitText(50); // AJT v20.2.1
}
```

When I run my application in debug mode and go to display any dialog which uses one of these controls I get an exception. I realise from this exception that the handle to the control is `null`.

So what is the right way to call `LimitText` in my derived combo without causing an exception?

Comment: Override `OnCreate`, call `LimitText` there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks.